# Grouping based on the order of data

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I have a set of data in the following format.

```
A
A
B
A
C
B
B
C
```

I want to group the data in such a way that the result should be grouped by alphabet and is should be based on order. For example for the above data the output should be

```
A - 2
B - 1
A - 1
C - 1
B - 2
C - 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need any of those messy `<br/>` tags, either!

Comment: So you want to count the running streaks?

Answer (score 0):

Create variables to keep track of the last letter and count.  Then loop over the letters and emit the data whenever the letter changes.

```
List<char> letters = new List<char>() { 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C' };

char last = letters.First();
int count = 1;
foreach (char letter in letters.Skip(1))
{
    if (letter == last)
    {
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(last + " - " + count);
        last = letter;
        count = 1;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(last + " - " + count);
```

The first character is handled outside of the loop by setting `last = letters.First()`, so the `foreach` loop starts with the second character by calling `letters.Skip(1)`.

The last `Console.WriteLine` is there to handle the final character block.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice LINQ extension to do what you want, created by [Eric White](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/04/21/the-groupadjacent-extension-method.aspx). You can use the following extension method to get adjacency grouping:

```
 public static class LINQExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupAdjacentBy<TElement, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TElement> source, Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        List<TElement> elements = null;
        TKey key = default(TKey);
        TKey lastKey = default(TKey);
        foreach (var x in source)
        {
            key = keySelector(x);
            if (elements != null && elements.Any() && !comparer.Equals(lastKey, key))
            {
                yield return new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(lastKey, elements);
                elements = null;
            }
            if (elements == null)
            {
                elements = new List<TElement>();
                lastKey = key;
            }
            elements.Add(x);
        }
        if (elements != null && elements.Any())
        {
            yield return new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(key, elements);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TElement, TElement>> GroupAdjacentBy<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> source, IEqualityComparer<TElement> comparer = null)
    {
        return source.GroupAdjacentBy(keySelector: x => x, comparer: comparer);
    }

    // implement IGrouping
    public class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
    {
        public TKey Key { get; private set; }
        private List<TElement> Elements { get; set; }
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<TElement>)this).GetEnumerator();
        }
        IEnumerator<TElement> IEnumerable<TElement>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<TElement>)Elements).GetEnumerator();
        }
        public Grouping(TKey key, List<TElement> elements)
        {
            Key = key;
            Elements = elements;
        }
    }
}
```

For a driver program, consider the following:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)     
     {
        List<String> list = new List<string>() { "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A"};
        var groups = list.GroupAdjacentBy(x => x);

        foreach(var group in groups)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key: {0}, Count: {1}", group.Key, group.Count()));

        Console.ReadLine();
     }

}
```

[Try it out at IDEOne](http://ideone.com/TQ28NN)

Output will be roughly:

```
Key: A, Count: 2
Key: B, Count: 3
Key: A, Count: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to do it in more functional way (not very successful though). The idea is to increment gorup by criteria when the previous element doesn't equal to the current one:

```
    class ElementWithGroup
    {
        public string Element { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public int Group { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<string>
        {
            "A",
            "A",
            "B",
            "A",
            "C",
            "B",
            "B",
            "C"
        };

        var helpList = list
            .Select((e, i) => new ElementWithGroup { Element = e, Index = i, Group = 0 })
            .ToList();

        var result = helpList
            .GroupBy(e => {
                var previous = e.Index == 0 ? null : helpList.ElementAt(e.Index - 1);
                if (previous != null)
                {
                    e.Group = previous.Element == e.Element ? previous.Group : previous.Group + 1;
                }
                return e.Group;
            });
    }
```

I'm not happy with this solution, and I'd rather do it in iterative way, but maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] letters = new string[] { "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C" };

int gindex = 0;
var v = letters.Select((x, i) => { return (i == 0 || x == letters[i - 1]) ? new { L = x, G = gindex } : new { L = x, G = ++gindex }; }).GroupBy(x => x);

foreach (var x in v) {
    Console.WriteLine(x.Key.L + " - " + x.Count());
}
```